# How do you add an element after a certain elements using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, element

I want to add an element directly after a certain element on a web page using JavaScript.

I also want to add it after every occurrence of this certain element.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Node.insertBefore()` and `Document.querySelectorAll()`.

Say you want to add an element `div` after each `div` with the class `.after-me`:

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll("div.after-me");

elements.forEach((e) => {
    const newNode = document.createElement("div");
    const nextSibling = e.nextSibling;
    if (nextSibling === null) {
        e.parentNode.appendChild(newNode);
    } else {
        e.parentNode.insertBefore(nextSibling, newNode);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can do it like this

```
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>

  <script>
    let div = document.querySelectorAll("div");
    let para = document.querySelectorAll("div");    
    let p = document.createElement("p")

    div.forEach((d => {    
      d.append(p)
    }))

    para.forEach((p => {    
      p.append("Hello World")
    }))
 </script>
```

We are getting all `<div>`s and then for each one we are are appending a `<p>` then we get all `<p>`s and for each one we are appending the words hello world.

In jQuery you can do it like this

```
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>

  <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    $( "div" ).append( "<p>Hello World</p>" );    
  </script>
```

This is shorter as jQuery finds all `<div>`s and appends the `<p>` and text all in one line

Comment: Does querySelectorAll work for class name, it turns out I need to getelemenybyclassname and append each.

Comment: Yes you can do `document.querySelectorAll(".yourClassNameHere")` dot and your class name. or `document.querySelectorAll("#yourIdNameHere")` # and your ID name